Como Liberar acesso do WebSocket no SprinSecurity?
Eu já pesquisei em todo o Stack BR e na Gringa e não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar. Gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver este problema.
Possuo um projeto onde uso SpringBoot, SpringSecurity e WebSocket com o Front-End em Angular.
Eu desenvolvi primeiro todo o projeto SpringBoot e WebSocket e agora por fim estou implementando o Security. O que ocorre, eu já configurei o Security e ele está funcionando perfeitamente para qualquer requisição HTTP que eu faça. Contudo, o problema está ocorrendo quando eu tenho me conectar com o WebSocket a partir do Front-End.
No meu Front-End eu tenho o seguinte Web-Socket-Service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { WEBSOCKET_PATH } from '../environments/environment';
import { Stomp } from '@stomp/stompjs';
import * as SockJS from "sockjs-client";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebSocketService {
  private stompClient: any;

  constructor() { }

  connect(): Observable<any> {
    const socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws");
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.stompClient.connect({}, (frame: any) => {
        observer.next(frame);
      });
    });
  }

  disconnect(): void {
    if (this.stompClient) {
      this.stompClient.disconnect();
    }
  }

  subscribe(destination: string, callback: (message: any) => void): void {
    if (this.stompClient) {
      this.stompClient.subscribe(destination, (message: any) => {
        callback(JSON.parse(message.body));
      });
    }
  }

  sendMessage(destination: string, message: any): void {
    if (this.stompClient) {
      this.stompClient.send(destination, {}, JSON.stringify(message));
    }
  }
}

Este Service é o responsável por realizar a conexão com o WebSocket, se inscrever num tópico, enviar a mensagem e se desconectar. Antes de eu implementar o Security, ele funcionava perfeitamente. No entanto, a partir do momento que implementei o Security, quando eu chamo o método .connect(); ele acusa erro na linha const socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws");. A mensagem de erro é a seguinte no console:
GET http://localhost:8080/ws/info?t=1714074349054 403 (Forbidden) web-socket.service.ts:16

Eu tentei configurar o Security para liberar a rota do WebSocket, mas mesmo assim o problema persiste. Eu configurei da seguinte forma:
Security Configs:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    SecurityFilter securityFilter;

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/api/account/authLogin",
            "/api/account/create"
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/ws/*").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

WebSocket Config
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS(); // Endpoint do WebSocket
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}

Quando testo pelo Postman, este método GET com a URL funciona perfeitamente, mas pelo Front não funciona. Alguém possuí alguma sugestão?

Estava testando algumas possibilidades por aqui para liberar as rotas e consegui resolver este problema colocando dois * no caminho.
Ficou assim:
.requestMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll()

